# NSPredicate with Custom NSObject

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Usually when trying to create a `NSPredicate` you would use a `NSString`, `NSNumber` or `NSDate`. I'm trying to create a `NSPredicate` from a unspecified class.

This is how I'm creating the predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"property == %@", value];
```

If value is a `NSString`, this works fine, but if I create a `MyIdObject`and I set value to be a `MyIdObject` I get slightly different predicates

These is the po result of the predicates I get:

With `NSString`: property == "123"

With `MyIdObject`: property == 123

Since the identifier is being saved as a `NSString` in `CoreData`, this is enough to make the predicate fail.

I know the 123 is being returned from the description method.

Simply adding the needed " in the predicate format is not a solution because then I will just get property == "%@"

For some reason when the `NSString` is returned from the `MyIdObject` it is treated differently from just having a `NSString`. Is there any solution for this?

Trying to simplify the question: I want to create a predicate using any `NSObject` as the value and not a `NSString`, although the value is saved as a `NSString` in `CoreData`. Is that possible?

Comment: I want to help you, but after 10 readings I can't make head or tail of what you are trying to ask. Could you proof read / rewrite ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a paragraph at the end. Hope this improves the question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by these two statements "the identifier is being saved as a NSString in CoreData" and "the NSString is returned from the MyIdObject"?  If you are saving some form of identifier to your MyIdObject, then your predicate must use the same identifier - it can't just try to use the MyIdObject itself.

Comment: The predicate is being used to fetch data from CoreData. "property" in a CoreData attribute with type NSString.
 
Using the MyIdObject object was exactly what I wanted. I had hoped the NSPredicate would use the description method and get a string that would be used to fetch the results. It does get a NSString from the description method, but since the object that I send to the predicateWithFormat method as a parameter is not a NSString, it doesn't escape the final predicate correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is not a kind of `NSString` class and therefore is not escaped like a string.

You have to use the `description` method explicitly or provide predicate with string formatted on your own.

```
DSIdentifier* dataSource = [DSIdentifier new];
dataSource.identifier = @"identifier";
// the first method
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"property = %@", dataSource.description];
// the second method
NSPredicate* otherPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"property = \"%@\"", dataSource]];

NSLog(@"predicate: %@, other predicate: %@", predicate, otherPredicate);
// predicate: property == "identifier", other predicate: property == "identifier"
```

Comment: Thanks Turekj. I'd rather not invoke description directly because I wanted to keep that code as generic as possible and this would cause problems with NSDates. Similar situation to just escaping the string myself.

I did try to change the description method of my class to escape the string correctly and although I got what seemed like the correct predicate (listReference == "1"), the fetch still failed.